# can I create a secondary set of categories for each product?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have PrestaShop 1.7.1.2 installed and I'm trying to create a 2nd set of categories to be used in a car accessories shop.

for example.. some of my main categories include `speakers`, `wheel covers` and `multimedia systems` but I also want each product to contain a secondary category that includes the `car company` -> `brand` -> `year` -> `doors count`.

so each customer will have all the main categories shown on the front page, but will also have a component to enter his car type and to get the relevant products specific to his car.

so in general I want each product to have two defined categories.. one main (for example `speakers`) and one secondary (for example `AUDI` ,`A1` ,`2010-2016`, `3 doors`.

how can I implement such a thing ? I'm a good programmer, if needed I'll write a relevant plugin if none can suite my needs.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is nested categories, which is actually already implemented in Prestashop. You don't have to code anything specificly.

To show main categories you can use this method :

```
Category::getCategories($idLang = false, $active = true, $order = true, $sqlFilter = '', $orderBy = '', $limit = '');
```

Or the category three :

```
Category::getNestedCategories( $idRootCategory = null,
    $idLang = false,
    $active = true,
    $groups = null,
    $useShopRestriction = true,
    $sqlFilter = '',
    $orderBy = '',
    $limit = ''
);
```

If you need to show only for one product you can also use :

```
Product::getProductCategories($id_product = '');
```

If you need anything, just look at classes directory, there is everything inside.

Comment: hi! I just want to make sure I fully described the issue.. I want to have two types of nested categories... and then the user will have two search engines available one for each category. one for the product type category, and one for car type. just to create all this nested categories and attach each product to two types of nested categories ? how can I have two separate search modules, one for each nested category type ?

Comment: Actually you have to make a module and reproduce what they did with Categories. There is no such thing as Taxonomy or custom post type to help you in Prestashop.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this with default Prestashop feature. If you want to create second set of categories, create one keeping parent as Home like given below:**
[image]

**After this you can map your product (Test product in below example) with both these categories like below for Men and Women:
And after this is done then you are a good programmer so you can override files to make single search field work for searching all categories.**

[image: Men]

[image: Women]

**Please let me know if you have any other queries or if I misunderstood your requirement.**

Comment: thank you for this amazing answer. what I need is that the 2nd set of categories (car type nested categories) won't show up in the left side filters since there are so different cards, models years and doors. instead I want the left side panel with the filters to show only the main nested categories, and I want the homepage to include a search component for the 2nd set of nested categories to allow free text with auto completion to each field in the nested categories.